# asp.net model can't enter in if (ModelState.IsValid)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So there is my code from a controller and at first i was stuck because data was not entering into the database and the VS didn't showed any errors. But now i've put a breakpoint in my if condition (Upsert POST method) and the 'Watch 1' showing me strange things like "Model.Product.Id    error CS0103: The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context" and "$exception   error CS0103: The name '$exception' does not exist in the current context".

```
namespace KeramoShop.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller

    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

        public ProductController(ApplicationDbContext db, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            _db = db;
            _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Product> objList = _db.Product;
            foreach (var obj in objList)
            {
                obj.Category = _db.Category.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == obj.CategoryId);
            }
            return View(objList);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// GET method for CREATE
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IActionResult Upsert(int? id)
        {
            //IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryDropDown = _db.Category.Select(i=> new SelectListItem { 
            //Text = i.Name,
            //Value = i.Id.ToString()
            //});

            //ViewBag.CategoryDropDown = CategoryDropDown;

            //Product product = new Product();

            ProductVM productVM = new ProductVM()
            {
                Product = new Product(),
                CategorySelectList = _db.Category.Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.Name,
                    Value = i.Id.ToString()
                })
            };


            if (id == null)
            {
                return View(productVM); //Для создания
            }
            else
            {
                productVM.Product = _db.Product.Find(id);
                if (productVM.Product == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return View(productVM);
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// POST method for CREATE
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] //-Токен защиты от взлома
        public IActionResult Upsert(ProductVM productVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
                string webRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;

                if (productVM.Product.Id == 0)
                {
                    string upload = webRootPath + WC.ImagePath;// Создание
                    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    string extention = Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName);

                    //var oldFile = Path.GetCombine (upload, objFromDb.Image)

                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(upload, fileName + extention), FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        files[0].CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }

                    productVM.Product.Image = fileName + extention;
                    _db.Product.Add(productVM.Product);
                }
                else
                {
                    var objFromDb = _db.Product.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == productVM.Product.Id);
                    //обновление
                    if (files.Count > 0)
                    {
                        string upload = webRootPath + WC.ImagePath;// Создание
                        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                        string extention = Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName);

                        var oldFile = Path.Combine(upload, objFromDb.Image);

                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(oldFile))
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(oldFile);
                        }

                        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(upload, fileName + extention), FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            files[0].CopyTo(fileStream);
                        }
                        productVM.Product.Image = fileName + extention;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        productVM.Product.Image = objFromDb.Image;
                    }
                }

                _db.Product.Update(productVM.Product);

                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else return View(productVM);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Get for Delete
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Id"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || id == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var obj = _db.Product.Find(id);

            if (obj == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(obj);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// POST for Delete
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] //-Токен защиты от взлома
        public IActionResult DeletePost(int id)
        {

            var obj = _db.Product.Find(id);
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            _db.Product.Remove(obj);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
    }
}
```

my Product Model

```
namespace KeramoShop.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Имя не может быть пустым")]
        [Display(Name = "Название")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Описание")]
        public string? Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Цена не может быть пустой")]
        [Display(Name = "Цена")]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Цена должна быть больше нуля")]
 
        public double Price { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Фотография")]
        public string? Image { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Тип категории")]

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Product VS Model

```
namespace KeramoShop.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class ProductVM
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategorySelectList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My View for Upsert

```
@model KeramoShop.Models.ViewModels.ProductVM


@{
    var title = "Создать продукт";
}

<form method ="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @if (Model.Product.Id !=0)
   {
     title = "Редактировать продукт";   
   <input asp-for="Product.Id" hidden />
   }
    <div class= "border p-3">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <h2 class="text-info pb-4">@title</h2>
        </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8">

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-4 pb-4">
                           <label asp-for="Product.Name"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input asp-for="Product.Name" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Product.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-4 pb-4">
                            <label asp-for="Product.Price"></label>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input asp-for="Product.Price" class="form-control" />
                             <span asp-validation-for="Product.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>

                        
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-4 pb-4">
                            <label asp-for="Product.Description"></label>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <textarea asp-for="Product.Description" class="form-control summernote"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                     <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-4 pb-4">
                            <label asp-for="Product.Image"></label>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input type="file" name="files" id="uploadBox" multiple class="form-control" />
                             
                        </div>
                    </div>


                     <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-4 pb-4">
                            <label asp-for="Product.CategoryId"></label>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">

                            <select asp-for="Product.CategoryId" asp-items="@Model.CategorySelectList" class="form-control">
                                <option disabled selected>--Выбeрите категорию-- </option>
                            </select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="Product.CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-8 offset-4 row p-3">

                            <div class="col">
                                    @if (Model.Product.Id != 0)
                                    {   //изменить
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info w-100" value="Обновить"/>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {    //создать
                                         <input type="submit" onclick="return validateInput()" class="btn btn-info w-100" value="Создать"/>
                                    }
                                </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                   <a asp-action = "Index" class="btn btn-success w-100"> Отмена </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    @* Keep this empty *@
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    

</form>

@section Scripts 
{
    @{ <partial name = "_ValidationScriptsPartial" />}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.summernote').summernote({height:250});
        });
        function validateInput() {
            if (document.getElementById("uploadBox").value == "") {
                Swal.fire(
                    'Ошибка!',
                    'Пожалуйста, загрузите картинку!',
                    'error')
                return false;
            }
            else return true;   
        }
    </script>
}
```

I'm new to asp.net and programming itself so I have no idea what i did wrong. I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Set a break point here: public IActionResult Upsert(ProductVM productVM) and look into the productVM. Make sure the model binder is working as expected. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @Waragi
okay! thank you! so i see 3 of my required properties is null (https://ibb.co/C1rsY2w) and i guess my problem is something with CategorySelectList but now i can't understand what's the problem is... but thank you!

Comment: If you post the View, I could shed some more light on your problem.

Comment: @Waragi
Updated my post with the View! Also I've tried to Edit my Product from browser and the "id" is working right, it turns null only when the product creating. But the "image" still null if i'm trying to upload it.

Comment: You would need to declare:  public byte[] Files{ get; set; }  in your Product model.

Comment: @Waragi 
Okay, thanks!
So i'll fix the problem with my image upload but my "CategorySelectList" and "Category" will remain null?

Comment: " but my "CategorySelectList" and "Category" will remain null?" Because in your code , you write"<select asp-for="Product.CategoryId" asp-items="@Model.CategorySelectList" class="form-control">" , you put the selected Category into the `CategoryId`, and don't send the list from view to controller , so in  Upsert POST method "CategorySelectList" will remain null.

Comment: ""Category" will remain null' is because  "[ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }" ,then in your Project table in database, you don't have `Category` column.

Answer (score 0):

> But the "image" still null if i'm trying to upload it.

You need to keep the name is the same as your `Image`.

In your Product model, write like below:

```
 public IList<IFormFile> Image { get; set; }
```

And in the view, change your `name="files"` into `name="Product.Image"`

Comment: Hi @dorian moor  , any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know? 
Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.